Auto Build Issues with Inteliji Version: 2024.1 Build: 241.14494.240
Since i've updated Inteliji IDE, i keep getting the following error for Auto Build for Java Project.
I've tried to clear cache, reset the IDE, delete .iml files, unchecked "Deleagte IDE Build", etc..,but it does not seems to work.
Is anyone facing same issues.
See my screenshot below.
Image Error Here
clear cache
reset the IDE
delete .iml files
unchecked "Deleagte IDE Build"

There is related issue under investigation: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209711
Please follow it for updates.
